# git add ignored files from within Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I would like to add a file that matches `.gitignore` therefore does not show up in Github Desktop. Normally, `git add -f ignoredFile` will do it, but I would like to do it from within Github Desktop. Any way of doing that?

Comment: Github Desktop is a convenient GUI to do the most common tasks, however it is not intended to do everything.  You still have to drop down to the command line to do less common tasks.  This falls under the less common tasks umbrella.

Comment: I always found the CLI interface most intuitive, easy to use. However, I really do not like to make regular end users to poke their head into the terminal, especially when they do NOT enjoy doing that.

Comment: In that case, you would need to find a different GUI that supports this feature.

Comment: I liked SourceTree and SmartGit. However, as you can see, they are a bit complex for general purpose usage if you dont expect your collaborators to learn all those terminology and so on.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it through the GitHub Desktop client UI.

On the Mac (should be similar to Windows), go to menu bar:

Repository -> Repository Settings -> Ignored Files

Add (copy the ignored from your `.gitignore` file) the ignored files in this text box and click save.

Then the ignored files should not be shown in uncommitted changes.

Comment: I am not saying I want the ignored files to "now show up". I want to perform a `git add -f ignoredFile.txt` from within Github Desktop in a simple, clear and intuitive way.

Comment: I added the files by right-clicking add to .gitignore but they continue to show up under changes

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note that I have experienced using the Github Desktop GUI Client:

If you commit and sync a file that you **later** want to add to gitignore, the best way to do so is to remove the file from the repository, commit, and sync the change. Then re-import the same file into the file directory it was in and you will see the file ignored in the Desktop Client. I was experiencing issues of gitignore not grabbing the file to ignore, due to it being originally checked into the repository. The above fixes that small issue within the GUI Client.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is what worked for me:

1. edit (or even delete) the .gitignore file such that the file is no longer ignored
2. make your commit (without including the change to .gitignore)
3. discard changes to .gitignore